# I have issue with Chrome precisly next block of JS code, work well in Firefox, but in Chrome will show original (uploaded) image size

Tags: javascript, python, flask, bootstrap-4

This is the javascript code. It works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome:

```
let big_image = document.getElementById('big_image');
let small_image = document.getElementById('small_image').getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < small_image.length; i++){
    small_image[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        let image_src = this.getAttribute('src');
        big_image.innerHTML = "<img src=" + image_src + " width='400px' height='400px'>";

    });
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="big_image">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/' + product.image_1) }}" alt="{{ product.name }}" width="400" height="400">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Product name: {{ product.name }}</h3>
            <hr>
            <p>Price: &euro;{{ product.price }}</p>
            {% if product.discount > 0 %}
                <p>Discount: {{ product.discount }}%</p>
            {% endif %}
            <strong>Description:</strong>
            <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 mt-3" id="small_image">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/' + product.image_1) }}" alt="{{ product.name }}" width="120" height="120" class="p-3">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/' + product.image_2) }}" alt="{{ product.name }}" width="120" height="120" class="p-3">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/' + product.image_3) }}" alt="{{ product.name }}" width="120" height="120" class="p-3">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `src` attribute of the image.

Instead of writing

```
big_image.innerHTML = "<img src=" + image_src + " width='400px' height='400px'>";
```

you should write

```
big_image.innerHTML = "<img src='" + image_src + "' width='400px' height='400px'>";
```

The variable `image_src` doesn't have the '' around it, so you have to add them manually